# Hardware Level Query for Pi Version

Tags: hardware, bash, pi-models

Is there a way you can query the model and revision of a Pi from a script without accessing files that are generated at install time for the OS? I have a project where a web page needs to display the model and revision of the Pi it is installed on, and I'm currently getting the info by looking at the revision number in /proc/cpuinfo. However, that file is populated when the OS is installed. The goal is to be able to have a single image that can be installed on either the Pi 2 or 3 and the page should be able to identify the model regardless of which Pi the image is installed onto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files inside /proc are not "installed".

/proc is a **virtual filesystem**. No files inside /proc exist on the SD Card.
They are created by Linux on every reboot and only exist inside RAM.
Try the following command to get a model name, for example:

```
 cat /proc/device-tree/model
```

Linux itself will create, delete and modify files inside /proc to represent internals (id + memory addresses of processes, CPU cores, USB devices etc. etc.)

**The files inside /proc will always be different even if all your Pis run the same image.**

Comment: Huh... that's interesting. I've tried the same image on two different Pi's though and both said Pi 3 when one of them was a Pi 2, and I was grabbing from /proc/cpuinfo. I assumed since the image was made when that file already existed, then installing the image on another Pi would result in the same info in that file.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Later model Pi2 use the same SOC as Pi3

Comment: Right, but the revision number is different for every model. That's what I was looking at. The problem was that I forgot to delete the page that was generated with the info already on it before creating the image. I just needed to delete it so it would re-create the file with the correct info on the page.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate the answer from *@flakeshake*: files under `/proc/` and `/sys/` are called **pseudo files**. They are the interface from the kernel to the user space. The kernel shows its settings with them. So if looking at `/proc/cpuinfo` you get the info from the kernel it just see at the time you ask for it, e.g. with `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

You can also modify the kernel settings by writing to pseudo files. For example look at network settings with `ls -l /proc/sys/net/ipv4`. Nearly all pseudo files there are writable so you can fine tune your network but you can also make it complete unusable ...

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau You can respect it by upvote ...

Comment: I did, but it's not visible because I only just joined this particular community.